# get data from database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

iam looking to get the data from database .when i give the filename i want the pageinfo

```
   public string GetPageInfo(string filenames)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select pageinfo from T_Pages where @pagename=filenames", con);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pagename", "filenames");
        // int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["pageinfo"]));
            }
        }

        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Let us please increase the level of quality of the question. What is the PRObLem?

Comment: sorry.actually i am new in database .an error is shown "server.GetPageInfo(string)':not all code paths return a value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> public **string** GetPageInfo(string filenames)

your method asks for a string to be returned at the end of the blocks.

according to your method's flow, the last thing it has to do is to write the result/s in the `Console Window`

> if (reader.Read())
>               {
>                   **Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["pageinfo"]));**
>               }

you have to choices:

1. either change `public string GetPageInfo(string filenames)` to `public void GetPageInfo(string filenames)`; or,
2. return whatever column it is that you need from the database. that is changing:

> if (reader.Read())
>               {
>                   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["pageinfo"]));
>               }

to

> return reader["pageinfo"];

Comment: i choose the second choice but now  an error " implicitly convert type "object" to 'string'.an explicit conversion exists"

Comment: so can you Accept this answer?

Comment: is there any option?

Comment: @mr.cool you should convert/cast it to string variable -> `reader["pageinfo"].ToString();`

Comment: i try it.but now this error is shown "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid column name 'filenames'."

Comment: error is shown this line " using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())"

Comment: check your database table's column. as said in the error, you do not have any column that matches `filenames`

Comment: ya some spelling mistake .now its ok

Answer (score 0):

```
    int businessEntityID = 1;
string firstName = "Sander";
string middleName = null;
string lastName = "Rossel";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Person.Person SET FirstName = @FirstName, MiddleName = @MiddleName, LastName = @LastName WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", firstName);
    if (middleName == null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", middleName);
    }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", lastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BusinessEntityID", businessEntityID);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

i hope it's help you.